# Azure Devops deploying to IIS Site Application

Tags: azure-devops

What **Website name** is needed to be set in Release deployment stages in case I want to deploy to IIS application?

Example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's no specific website name that needs to be there. You decide what it is. If I'm correct, the 'Website Name' will be the name of the folder that Azure creates it under.But what you have there is not another Website. It's a subsite. Haven't tried with that. Shouldn't make a difference though

Comment: So the answer is simple as: TestSite\Subsite :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it was simple enough just to put Website name in azure as: {Website Name}\{Application Name} as for my example is TestSite\Subsite

Comment: Really thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept it as the answer? So it would be helpful for other community members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Thanks for your sharing again. Have a nice day.